# MSYS2 man: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/man_db.conf

Tags: command-line, bash, git, man, msys2

I'm on Windows 10 but using bash and [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org) (mingw64). I just installed man using MSYS2. The problem is when typing a command like `man echo` (can be any command; it doesn't have to be echo), I get this error:

> “man: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/man_db.conf”

The file exists. Weirdly, if I run the command in cmd it works.

I have bash installed both via MSYS2 and via git. Actually I've been having a lot of headaches because of duplicate installations from git and MSYS2 but now is not the time to tell all those stories.

I use the bash that comes installed with git and not with MSYS2 and I have my reasons for keeping it that way. But this error doesn't occur if I were to use the bash I have from MSYS2. Over there man works fine.

I read over the man options and tried playing with a few different paths using the `--manpath` option but no luck.

I also tried copy-pasting the man_db.conf from my `msys64/etc` folder to the `Git/etc` folder. This did make the error go away but instead man displays nothing then a bunch of tildes, so it's not really a solution. Also pursuing this solution means I will have to modify my git installation which is not a good idea.

EDIT: Better solutions still welcome but for now I found a workaround. Because man works in cmd, I added the following alias to my .bashrc:

> alias man='MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 cmd /c man'